# Angular ui-router Url localized

Tags: angularjs, localization, routes, angular-ui-router, angularjs-routing

I'd like to have localization in URL like this:

> http://example.com/de -> get German locale (DE)
>
> http://example.com/it -> get Italian locale (IT)

So I did an abstract route like this:

```
state('root', {
  abstract: true,
  url: '/{lang:(?:de|it)}',
});
```

And the home one like this:

```
state('root.home', {
  url: '',
});
```

And it works fine, but now the default root http://example.com/ is not working anymore.
I need to have `url: '/'` working like the other ones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it manually then, but it looks hacky way.

```
.state('root', {
  abstract: true,
  url: '/{lang:(?:de|it)}',
  params: {
     lang: null
  },
  controller: function($stateParams, $state){
    if(!$stateParams.lang){
      $state.go('.home')
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: The `params: {lang: null}` is what I was missing. Thanks.

Comment: No..we have set its defalut value to `null` if its not set.. And then we are redirecting to home state.